# Yii - render widget inside GridView cell

Tags: php, gridview, yii, widget

I would like to render widget inside a CGridView cell. How is that possible?

To be exact - I want to render TbProgress widget inside CGridView. I cannot find any solution for this so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What if you use the `template` property ?

Comment: what about custom DataColumn class?

Comment: You could simply use a custom function to render this cell. What did you try actually ?

Comment: I answered this on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465229/render-a-widget-inside-cgridview-in-yii/22583350#22583350.<br />
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In columns definition use function as `value`. In case function returns html use `type` as `raw`, so it will not be escaped. Function will get `$data` parameter with current model instance. Here is some simple example:

```
$this->widget('CGridView', [
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'columns' => [
          [
                'name' => 'title',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($data)
                {
                    return CHtml::link(MHtml::i18nGetValue($data, 'title'), ["page/update", "id" => $data->id]);
                },
          ],
....
```